Como Trabajan los Frames en Tkinter? Problemas con las dimensiones del Frame
Como impido que se muestre el mismo Frame en tkinter?
Tengo un inconveniente y lo mas cercano que encontre a mi problema es esta pregunta, me pasa algo similar, tengo un frame que se activa al dar click a un boton (self.Frame_Menu_Desplegable), tengo esta configuracion,
def Ventana_Principal(self):
    self.master.title(" MENU PRINCIPAL ")
    
    self.menu_principal = Frame(self, padx = 50, pady = 30, bg = "Yellow") 
    self.menu_principal.place(x = 0, y = 20)
    
    self.Frame_Menu_Desplegable = Frame(self, padx = 60, pady = 30, bg = "Red")
    self.Frame_Menu_Desplegable.place(x = 350, y = 20) 

def Mesa_Entrada(self):    
    self.borrar_frame()
    self.Menu_Desplegable_MesaEntrada = ttk.Treeview(self.Frame_Menu_Desplegable)
    self.Menu_Desplegable_MesaEntrada.pack(ipadx = 60, ipady = 10)   
    self.Menu_Desplegable_MesaEntrada.heading('#0', text = ' MESA DE ENTRADA ', anchor = CENTER)
    archivos = self.Menu_Desplegable_MesaEntrada.insert("", END, text = " INGRESO DE NOTAS ")
    self.Menu_Desplegable_MesaEntrada.insert(archivos, END, text = " INGRESO DE ACTAS DE DOCUMENTOS ", tags = "Ingreso_DOC")
    self.Menu_Desplegable_MesaEntrada.tag_bind("Ingreso_DOC", "<Double-Button-1>", self.ingreso_Notas)

en la funcion Mesa_Entrada, al hacer doble click en el item abre la ventana(otra hoja con un monton de funciones) en un toplevel PERO, es como que se vuelve a ejecutar la funcion del frame y lo va haciendo mas ancho cada vez que selecciono un item. En teoria funciona abre el toplevel, pero agranda o ensancha el frame desplegable, alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal? aclaro que no me pasa con todos los items que tengo.
He probado con grid, si bien no agranda, es decir cumple perfectamente, pero la columna no se visualiza con el ancho que prefiero.
